# Why Ajax doesn't load?

Tags: php, ajax, post

This is my code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Magento 2 </title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function ajaxCall(){
                    $.post( "insert.php", function( data ) {
                        alert(data);
                        //$( ".result" ).html( data );
                    });
                }
        </script>
        <a href ="" onclick ="javascript:ajaxCall();"style="text-decoration:none;"><input type ="button" value="Executa"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

the insert.php file contains:

```
<php 
   echo 1;
?>
```

I don't know what i wrote wrong ? It doesn't alert ! I tried to see also with firebug, but it doesn't display anything. Im wondering what im doing wrong ?. Thx

Comment: Answer to your next question: You aren't opening your PHP tag correctly `<php` should be `<?php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your href="" add a "#" or javascript:void(0)

like this it will work.

```
 <a href ="javascript:void(0)" onclick ="javascript:ajaxCall();"style="text-decoration:none;"><input type ="button" value="Executa"></a>
```

Comment: it works. but what does it  javascript:void(0) mean ?

Comment: you can say it just makes a link as dead. and onClick event will be called instead. doing only href="" infact  makes page to reload.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent the default event of the `a` tag:

**Javascript**

```
function ajaxCall(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post( "insert.php", function( data ) {
        alert(data);
                        //$( ".result" ).html( data );
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href ="" onclick ="javascript:ajaxCall(event);"style="text-decoration:none;"><input type ="button" value="Executa"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Different name for onclick handle and the real function.

```
 <a href="" onclick="ajaxCall();"style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="button" value="Executa"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a  inside an  tag doesn't work with every browser. Try to replace the  with a .

Answer (score 1):

need `href ="javascript:void(0);"`

try this

```
<a href ="javascript:void(0);" onclick ="ajaxCall();"style="text-decoration:none;"><input type ="button" value="Executa"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put that onclick functinality on the button. and avoid the  anchor tag. anchor tag by default got a functionality.

```
<input type ="button" value="Executa" onclick ="javascript:ajaxCall();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add "return false;" to the end of onclick function;

and

between onclick and style should have space 
:)

like this

```
<a href ="" onclick ="javascript:ajaxCall();return false;" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type ="button" value="Executa"></a>
```